# OR WHERE and AND in mySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically, I'm trying to get data from an SQL based on two different groups, `t.type` has to equal `single` and `t.status` has to equal `1` but as for `t.org` I want to it get both `DUAL` and `RA`, here's what I attempted to no avail.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT( p.tID ) 
FROM 
    ticket AS t 
INNER JOIN 
    people AS p ON t.ID = p.tID 
WHERE 
    t.type = 'single' AND t.status='1' AND t.org = 'RA' OR t.org = 'DUAL'
```

I'm pretty sure theirs a way to get this query working, just not in my head

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`AND` has higher [precedence](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/operator-precedence.html) than `OR`, so your existing expression is currently evaluated as:

```
WHERE 
    (t.type = 'single' AND t.status='1' AND t.org = 'RA') OR t.org = 'DUAL'
```

To force alternative logic, one needs to include explicit parentheses:

```
WHERE 
    t.type = 'single' AND t.status='1' AND (t.org = 'RA' OR t.org = 'DUAL')
```

However, in this case, one can use MySQL's [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in) operator instead of `OR`:

```
WHERE 
    t.type = 'single' AND t.status='1' AND t.org IN ('RA','DUAL')
```

Comment: That revision provides a much more simply response and allows me to write a shorter query

Comment: If this is the correct answer to your question please mark it as such.

Comment: I can't for another 2minutes, although once that time has passed I'll sure do so.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the IN condition:

```
WHERE 
    t.type = 'single' AND t.status = '1' AND t.org IN ('RA','DUAL')
```

Or you can use brackets to group conditions:

```
WHERE
    t.type = 'single' AND t.status = '1' AND (t.org = 'RA' OR t.org = 'DUAL')
```